# Keras model.predict giving different shape from training label array

Tags: tensorflow

I'm using the following code to try and learn tensorflow. I've clearly specified the shapes of the training and validation `X` and `y` arrays.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

f = lambda x: 2*x
Xtrain = np.random.rand(400,1)
ytrain = f(Xtrain)
Xval = np.random.rand(200,1)
yval = f(Xval)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()
             )

model.fit(Xtrain, ytrain, epochs=50, verbose=0)
```

When I run `yval.shape, model.predict(Xval).shape`, I get the output `((200, 1), (200, 10))`. I'm not able to understand where these extra 9 dimensions are coming from. Even the `Xval` prediction should have the shape `(200, 1)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A small correction is needed in the last `Dense Layer` of your `Network`.

Since you want to predict a `Numeric Value`, and as the Problem is `Regression`, **Last Dense Layer** should have only **`1 Neuron/Unit`** and the **`Activation Function`** in the **`Last Dense Layer`** should be **`linear`**.

So, replacing the code,

```
tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu')
```

with

```
tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='linear')
```

should resolve your issue.

Complete working code, whose `model.predict(Xval).shape` will be `(200,1)` is shown below:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

f = lambda x: 2*x
Xtrain = np.random.rand(400,1)
ytrain = f(Xtrain)
Xval = np.random.rand(200,1)
yval = f(Xval)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='linear')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()
             )

model.fit(Xtrain, ytrain, epochs=50, verbose=0)
```

We can have multiple `Units/Neurons` (equal to the number of `classes`) in the `Last Dense Layer` if the problem is `Classification` and each Output represents the `Probability` corresponding to each `Class`.

Comment: Regarding your comment on classification, I have a follow up query. I have a 1500 dimensional vector that I want to use as input feature. I use a model with a 500 neuron dense layer (relu) and a single neuron sigmoid layer. Compiled with binary cross entropy loss and Adam optimizer. But in that case the loss increases by a lot in each epoch. Also, if I use a standard dense single neuron layer (without specifying the activation), then it converges to -7 loss after a few epochs and stays there. Anything that I'm doing wrong in this case?

Comment: Hi, You can raise a New Issue and share the complete code so that I can look into it. Thanks!

Comment: will do so asap . Thank you!

Comment: I've created the new issue here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62952770/issue-with-tensorflow-classification-loss-not-decreasing