# Issue with Tensorflow classification - loss not decreasing

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Following is the reference code:

```
Xtrain2 = df2.iloc[:,:-1].values
ytrain2 = df2['L'].values.reshape((200,1))

print(Xtrain2.shape, ytrain2.shape)

#--------------------------

lrelu = lambda x: tf.keras.activations.relu(x, alpha=0.1)

model2 = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1501, input_dim=1501, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu'),
    #tf.keras.layers.Dense(1),
    #tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=lrelu)
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

model2.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

#--------------------------

model2.fit(Xtrain2, ytrain2, epochs=50)#, verbose=0)
```

Just a simple attempt at a classifier. The last layer is sigmoid since it's just a binary classifier. The loss is also appropriate for the problem. Dimension of input is 1500 and the number of samples is 200. I get the following output:

```
(200, 1501) (200, 1)
Train on 200 samples
Epoch 1/50
200/200 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/sample - loss: 0.4201 - accuracy: 0.0300
Epoch 2/50
200/200 [==============================] - 0s 359us/sample - loss: -1.1114 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 3/50
200/200 [==============================] - 0s 339us/sample - loss: -4.6102 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 4/50
200/200 [==============================] - 0s 344us/sample - loss: -13.7864 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 5/50
200/200 [==============================] - 0s 342us/sample - loss: -34.7789 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
.
.
.
Epoch 40/50
200/200 [==============================] - 0s 348us/sample - loss: -905166.4000 - accuracy: 0.3750
Epoch 41/50
200/200 [==============================] - 0s 344us/sample - loss: -1010177.5300 - accuracy: 0.3400
Epoch 42/50
200/200 [==============================] - 0s 354us/sample - loss: -1129819.1825 - accuracy: 0.3450
Epoch 43/50
200/200 [==============================] - 0s 379us/sample - loss: -1263355.3200 - accuracy: 0.3900
Epoch 44/50
200/200 [==============================] - 0s 359us/sample - loss: -1408803.0400 - accuracy: 0.3750
Epoch 45/50
200/200 [==============================] - 0s 355us/sample - loss: -1566850.5900 - accuracy: 0.3300
Epoch 46/50
200/200 [==============================] - 0s 359us/sample - loss: -1728280.7550 - accuracy: 0.3550
Epoch 47/50
200/200 [==============================] - 0s 354us/sample - loss: -1909759.2400 - accuracy: 0.3400
Epoch 48/50
200/200 [==============================] - 0s 379us/sample - loss: -2108889.7200 - accuracy: 0.3750
Epoch 49/50
200/200 [==============================] - 0s 369us/sample - loss: -2305491.9800 - accuracy: 0.3700
Epoch 50/50
200/200 [==============================] - 0s 374us/sample - loss: -2524282.6300 - accuracy: 0.3050
```

I don't see where I'm going wrong in the above code. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The loss is decreasing. -2 is less than -1.

Comment: Your's is the case of `Curse of Dimensionality` i.e., Number of Features are very very greater than Number of Samples. You need to either reduce the Number of Features, or increase the Number of Samples. The links, https://sebastianraschka.com/faq/docs/large-num-features.html, https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/08/dimensionality-reduction-techniques-python/ and https://towardsdatascience.com/dimensionality-reduction-for-machine-learning-80a46c2ebb7e may help you to reduce the number of Features. Hope this helps.

Comment: @TensorflowSupport: So the last dense layer in the model (1 neuron, sigmoid) is correct, right? I'm almost sure of it but still second-guessing myself. The reason I'm not sure is because model.predict gives float values. instead of the -1 or 1 labels

Comment: Sigmoid returns float values between 0 and 1. [tf.math.sigmoid](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/sigmoid) with examples.